# What does "it" refer to in "sweated it out"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

In the following sentence as an example :
"He sweated it out until the lab report was back",
What does "it" refer to in "sweated it out"?

I have just seen the example "if **it wasn't for** Amber…" whose meaning is "Without Amber…". How could we change "I sweated it out" so as to make its meaning more obvious like Amber's example?

English is a foreign language for me and I have no problem understanding the Amber's example. The example "I lost it" could be understood as I lost control or composure. In the same way, how can I understand the sentence in my question which sounds very alien to me as a French and Arabic speaker? I'm interested in the etymology or grammar of it, or in which way could it be transformed.

Comment: Compare [I lost it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156691/where-did-i-lost-it-come-from).

Comment: 'How could we change "I sweated it out" so as to make its meaning more obvious like Amber's example?' would be better expressed 'What is another way to express "I sweated it out" ' that doesn't use "it"? // A paraphrase is "I endured the [stressful] situation" (so some might argue that this "it" is semi-referential or quasi-referential, with 'it' referring to the [nasty] situation obtaining; referential it must correspond to a noun phrase that actually appears). With "It's raining" and "Had it not been for Holmes, we would never have solved this case", "it" is clearly non-referential.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster ["Sweat it out" is an idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweat%20it%20out#:~:text=US%20%3A%20to%20work%20hard%20at,give%20them%20the%20test%20results.) So, the dummy "it" substitutes "anxiety" "worry". There are many phrasal verbs and idioms that use "it" e.g. *feel it in your bones*, *pack it in*,  *take it easy* etc.

Comment: I believe the French "**S'il** vous plait" relies on a vague "it" or a situational one: If this pleases you = please.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Hits on searches for "sweated out the" have situations, not states of mind, as DOs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth John was sweating out all **the ill feeling** he felt towards the man who had cheated him of everything: wife, home and money.

Comment: When you sweat it out, you endure a situation (one that makes you anxious/sweat). So you could say that *it* is *the situation*.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat My first comment included <<  some might argue that this "it" is semi-referential or quasi-referential with 'it' referring to the [nasty] situation obtaining >>

Comment: There are other similar expressions, like "work it out" meaning to solve a problem.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I see. But I’m not quite sure I buy this: “referential *it* must correspond to a noun phrase” (or rather that *it*’s antecedent must be a noun phrase).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does “it” refer to in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606726/what-does-it-refer-to-in-this-sentence)

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat (1) Referential 'it' has to refer to some referent (by definition) and (2) the referent must be expressly specified in the text/speech somewhere. Perhaps you want to classify say ing-clauses / other nominals as different from NPs.

Comment: @Lambie No Google results found for "sweated out the ill feeling". The odd one for "sweated out all the/my anger". None for "sweated out all the anxiety" / "sweated out all my anxiety".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh please, **not everything is already written**. That's the whole point of creativity. You seem to not understand that.

Comment: @Lambie — *Sweating it out* has nothing to do with “detoxifying” here.

Comment: @TinfoilHat You didn't understand what I wrote. You wrote above: When you sweat it out, you endure a situation. **Right**. So, my sentence: John was sweating out all the ill feeling he felt towards the man who had cheated him of everything: wife, home and money. **means** John was enduring all the ill feeling etc. Perfectly reasonable. Many people here are not writers. That is typically the problem.

Comment: @Lambie The U in ELU stands for (established) usage. It's the distinctive of the site as compared with almost all other popular EL sites: the possibility, the requirement even, of offering valid data supporting the idiomaticity of various usages.  If you wish rather to discuss inventive / questionable usages, there are many other sites far more suitable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Writers trust what they know and have internalized. I took the idiom: "sweat **it** out" and gave it a direct object. This is allowable under English grammar rules. ELU stand for English Language Usage. Always counting on the "other" for what is "established" is a big problem on this site. Sometimes, "the other" is just one of us.

Comment: Ngrams: FOUND INSIDE – PAGE 356
... **sweat out a lean period without going to pieces** . Iowa State Federation of Labor · 1947 · ‎Snippet view

Answer (score 1):

As [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) state, the word *it* "appears with no identifiable independent meaning in a large number of generally colloquial idioms," like *hit it off,* *play it safe,* and *cool it* (p. 1483). *Sweat it out* is one such idiom; the word *it* there doesn't refer to anything, but just acts as an object without contributing anything to the sentence's meaning.

Comment: It refers to a pre-existing situation or condition. And I have to say that that's obvious. Otherwise, there's no point in even saying it....

Comment: @Lambie So why can't we say "He sweated the situation out"?

Comment: You can. I see no reason why not.

Comment: Unlike the pronoun, which is required to split the phrasal verb (*sweat it out* not *\*sweat out it*), the noun phrase can go in between or after. Where *sweat out* is  figurative, *He sweated out the situation* is more natural. But if we are talking about literal sweat, then *He sweated the alcohol out* is perhaps more natural.